# How to insert an array of items in sqlite using angularjs and ionic

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

Is there a way to loop through linked values in angular to download a list of objects in a sqlite database. The tables am working on are modules, courses and library. So now when I download an item in courses it shows a linked reference to modules which tells me I have 4 or 2 link references based on that particular course then the second step comes in where that module has a linked reference to library the final table.

My question is how will i use a angular.forEach statement to loop through the first two tables and download the the course and the linked modules together.

```
modules.forEach(function(item) {
                        var lib ={};
                        lib._id = item._id;
                        lib.name = item.name;
                        lib.course = item.course;
                        lib.tests = item.tests;
                        lib.libraryItems = item.libraryItems;
                        console.log(lib);
                        return lib;
                    })

                lib.forEach(function(item){
                    var no = {};

                    no._id = item._id;
                    no.TextContent = item.TextContent;
                    no.HtmlContentBase64 = item.HtmlContentBase64;
                })
```

The code snippet I have above can list the items from the other table in my course table but only shows one instance of it. The second part of the code am still testing it now to see if am on the right track. Any assistance is greatly  appreciated.

Comment: I just figured out how to achieve what I wanted to. First of all my first table is easy to get so I can run a normal ionic sqlite method to add the data into the database, underneath my db.transaction statement I then use the modules.forEach as show above but  with its own db.transaction statement inside to allow the data to be inserted a certain number of times based on the the number of loops the forEach statement makes.

Comment: In addition as I have 3 tables I used a second forEach method in the first one. I placed it on the reference value of libraryItems in courses to also loop through the values, after which it also gets its own db.transaction statement to insert data like the previous statements.